# Min-width Media Query displaying at the incorrect specified amount

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

This is a really strange problem, because I have not come across any media query problems in many months, but this one has stumped me.

I have a simple min-width definition to show the user name in the header if there is sufficient width:

```
.userFullName {
  @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, according to Chrome's ruler, the media query is only getting applied at 1000px. At 999px and below, it disappears... so it seems like it's 200 pixels off exactly.

I'd post images to show what I mean, but I don't have enough rep.

I am not understanding why it would do this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: That is not how you use media queries … the `@media` has to be the “outside” part, and the complete rule(s) including the selector go on the “inside”.

Comment: I'm using sass, which allows this. I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: OK, fair enough. But you should still provide an online example where we can have a look at this ourselves.

Comment: Okay, I have to put one together. Just to test, I wrote it the way Akhil specified - same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write like this

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .userFullName {display: inline-block;
}  
}
```

Otherwise please check is there any other media-query that over-writing this.